# Restore desktop keyboard to windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard

My primary desktop workstation runs 8.1 and synchs it's settings to my OneDrive space.

I just took delivery of a HPStream 7 - signed into my microsoft account and allowed it to synch PC settings.  I should _not have done that. The synch has overwritten my desktop pc's keyboad settings - it no longer enters any text.

I've powered off...plugged in a different keyboard - removed the driver and rebooted - re-installed MS's Mouse and Keyboard center all with no joy.

I notice in Device manager that only the generic 'HID input device' shows in the Keyboard node - even though I have keyboard-specific drivers present.

The keyboard is detected by Windows - MS's Mouse and Keyboard Center can detect whether the MS keyboard or my Logictech keyboard is hooked up. at each keypress, I get a audible 'click' (and no, not that *keyboard buffer full* behavior) - but no OS/program response. The keyboard is responsive during bootup - i'm using it to enter my password. But as soon as i get to the desktop it only responds with no input makes it to any of my programs.

So how do I convince windows to, once again, look to my physical keyboard for input?

Comment: I am 99.9% certain you synching your devices has nothing to do with your keyboard not working.  That just isn't something that is synced between your devices.  This is based on the fact I have multiple Windows 8.1 devices ( Generic Desktop, Vista Era Laptop, Surface 3 Pro ) all connected to the same Microsoft Account.

Comment: Though functionality in the pre-boot environment would seem to render this moot, I still wonder what would happen if you plugged the keyboard into a different system?

Comment: Both keyboards that i've tried work correctly on other systems. The desktop is now (not before) showing the same 'thicker cursor' and audible clicks as have been set (only) on the tablet.